# How do i drop the first string in a sentence in R using gsub

Tags: r, string, function

```
ex03ProperNoun <- function(text) {
  assertString(text)
  words <- unique(grep('(?<!\\.[.!?]\\s)[A-Z][a-z0-9]+',
                       strsplit(text, ' ')[[1]], value = TRUE, perl = TRUE))
  words <- sub("^\\w", "", text)
  index <- grep('\\.\\s?[A-Z][a-z0-9]+', text, perl = TRUE)[1]
  if (!is.na(index)) {
    words <- words[(-index)]
  }
  return(words)
}
```

what do I have to change so that it drops the first word in the text gets dropped.

i tried to change

```
words <- sub("^\\w", "", text)
```

but it did not work

Comment: You have to give an example of the string you have and what you want to drop from it

Comment: To drop the first string, `sub("^\\S+\\s", "", text)`

Comment: @Onyambu f.e we have "Proper Nouns Nouns are usually Capitalized."
the output should be every capitalized word beside the first word at the beginning so: "Nouns", "Capitalized"

Comment: You still have to give an example. Without example no one can visualize what problem you are facing. Try the code I gave

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues.  First,

```
words <- sub("^\\w", "", text)
```

is overwriting the vector you created on the previous line (it's working on `text` instead of `words`).  And all it will do is remove any leading word character of each element, not the first word.

I'd suggest replacing that line with

```
words <- words[-1]
```

which will remove the first word as you were asking.  Once you've done that, I'm not sure you need the logic underneath.

The only other thing you might want to do is check that `text` starts with a capital as expected, or you'll remove a word you might not want to (tweaking your example

```
ex03ProperNoun("proper Nouns Nouns are usually Capitalized.")
```

would remove "Nouns".